# Filtrar datos en tabla con relacion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero obtener todos los usuarios que no se encuentran asociados a un empleado.

En la tabla empleado tengo un campo user_id donde le asigno al empleado el usuario correspondiente.

Ahora quiero obtener todos los usuarios que no se encuentran asociado a los empleados.
Como lo podria hacer?

Actualmente estoy trantando de hacer lo siguiente

```
$usuarios = User::doesntHave('empleados')->get();

dd($usuarios);
```

y me arroja el error

```
Call to undefined method App\User::empleados()
```

Tabla Empleados

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('empleados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('legajo');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('first_name');

        $table->BigInteger('usuario_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('set null')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentando? ¿Qué error tiene? ¿Qué estructura tienen las tablas?

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo en laravel por eso consulto. No encontre mucho al respecto.

Comment: Pensaba usando whereHas

Comment: Tengo una relacion de 1:1

Comment: Ahi lo coloque, es como que no se encuentra definida una clase y me parece raro eso

Comment: Ahi puse mi tabla empleados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu modelo `User` deberías tener un método del siguiente modo:

```
class User extends Models
{
    public function empleado()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(Empleado::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora en tu controlador deberías tener una consulta de esta forma:

```
$sinEmpleo = User::doesntHave('empleado')->get();
```

Consideraciones:

- El modelo `User` debe tener un método llamado `empleado` que haga relación o vincule con la tabla empleados
- Dado que es una relación de 1:1 debes indicar el nombre del método `empleado` en singular

Comment: @FrancoSanchez si me habia equivocado en el nombre del método, se me escapo una s, checa de nuevo

Comment: Esta tal cual me lo pusiste vos.

Comment: Perfecto quedo !